# YII :: CJuiDateTimePicker is not saving data into MySQL

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am using CJuiDateTimePicker in my yii application but can't save data into mysql. How can Save data into MySQL

CODE::

```
    <?php Yii::import('application.extensions.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker');
        $this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker',array(
            'model'=>$model, //Model object
            'attribute'=>'pp_date', //attribute name
            'language'=> '',
            'mode'=>'date', 
            'options'=>array(
                'showAnim'=>'fold',
                'changeMonth' => 'true',
                'changeYear' => 'true',
                'showOtherMonths' => 'true',
                'selectOtherMonths' => 'true',
                'showOn' => 'both',
        ),
    ));?>
```

Any Helps appreciated

Comment: Can you show us the validation rules from your model please?

Comment: I got the solutions. this not depends on rule. Just need the date format in options -> 'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Dat and Time format are mysql format (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss)

```
'options'   => array(
    'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy',
    'timeFormat' => 'hh:mm:ss', //'hh:mm tt' default 
),
```

I use such a structure:

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker');
$this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'date',
    'mode'=>'datetime', 
    'options'=>array(
        'showAnim'=>'slideDown',
        'hideIfNoPrevNext' => true,
        'timeFormat'=>'hh:mm:ss',
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'
),
```